# Theano gradient with function on tensors

Tags: python, theano, differentiation

I have a function that calculates a value of a scalar field on a 3D space, so I feed it 3D tensors for x, y and z coordinates (obtained by numpy.meshgrid) and use elementwise operations everywhere. This works as expected.

Now I need to calculate a gradient of the scalar field. I've been playing around with `theano.tensor.grad` and `theano.tensor.jacobian` and I don't understand how a derivative of elementwise operation is supposed to work.

This is a MWE that I don't understand:

```
import theano.tensor as T 

x, y = T.matrices("xy")

expr = x**2 + y
grad = T.grad(expr[0, 0], x)
print(grad.eval({x: [[1, 2], [1, 2]], y: [[1, 1], [2, 2]]}))
```

It prints

```
[[ 2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

while I would expect

```
[[ 2.  4.]
 [ 2.  4.]]
```

I also tried with jacobian:

```
import theano.tensor as T

x, y = T.matrices("xy")

expr = x**2 + y
grad = T.jacobian(expr.flatten(), x)
print(grad.eval({x: [[1, 2], [1, 2]], y: [[1, 1], [2, 2]]}))
```

which returns

```
[[[ 2.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  4.]
  [ 0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.]
  [ 2.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.]
  [ 0.  4.]]]
```

(the nonzero elements together would give me my expected matrix from the previous example)

Is there some way to get the elmentwise gradients I need?

Can I for example somehow define the function as scalar (three scalars into a scalar) apply it elementwise over the coordinate tensors? This way the derivative would also be just a simple scalar and everything would work smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element `expr[0,0]` as a cost with respect to `x` only relates to the first element of `x` thus the result you are receiving is correct.

The result you expect is produced if you sum the whole `expr` array. Theano will take care of backward propagating the gradient through the `sum`

```
import theano.tensor as T 

x, y = T.matrices("xy")

expr = x**2 + y
grad = T.grad(expr.sum(), x)
print(grad.eval({x: [[1, 2], [1, 2]], y: [[1, 1], [2, 2]]}))
```

prints

```
[[ 2.  4.]
 [ 2.  4.]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.